# Spark DataFrame Cache Large TempTable

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a spark application with a very large Dataframe.  I am currently registering the dataframe as a tempTable so I can perform several queries against it.

When I am using RDDs I use persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK()) what is the equivalent for a tempTable.

Below are two possibilities, I don't think option 2 will work because cacheTable tries to cache in memory and my table is too big to fit in memory.

```
    DataFrame standardLocationRecords = inputReader.readAsDataFrame(sc, sqlc);

    // Option 1 //
    standardLocationRecords.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());
    standardLocationRecords.registerTempTable("standardlocationrecords");

    // Option 2 //
    standardLocationRecords.registerTempTable("standardlocationrecords");
    sqlc.cacheTable("standardlocationrecords");
```

How can I best cache my temptable so I can perform several queries against it without having to keep reloading the data.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a look at Spark 1.6.1 source code and actually Option 2 is what you want.  Here's an excerpt from a comment on caching:

> ... Unlike `RDD.cache()`, the default storage level is set to be
>   `MEMORY_AND_DISK` because recomputing the in-memory columnar
>   representation of the underlying table is expensive.

```
  def cacheTable(tableName: String): Unit = {
    cacheManager.cacheQuery(table(tableName), Some(tableName))
  }

  private[sql] def cacheQuery(
      query: Queryable,
      tableName: Option[String] = None,
      storageLevel: StorageLevel = MEMORY_AND_DISK): Unit
```

Reference:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L355

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L76